# Upgrade of spring-security-config version from v5.6.3 to v6.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-config

I need to upgrade spring-security-config(version 5.6.3) dependency in our project to remove any vulnerabilities it includes. The project references spring boot version 2.7.3. spring-security-config is added into the project using spring-boot-starter-security.

Now, to remove any kind of vulnerability, I need to upgrade spring-security-config to version 6.1.2 which is probably introduced by spring-boot-starter-security 3.1.2. What would be the best way to make an upgrade?

1. Just upgrade spring-security-config version to 6.1.2 without upgrading spring-boot-starter-security and spring boot version. Would this new upgraded version be compatible with old spring-boot-starter-security as mentioned above?
2. Upgrade spring-boot-starter-security version (3.1.2) without upgrading spring-boot version of the project (v2.7). Would this be compatible and follows the norms?

Thanks

Comment: you should never have manual version numbers in your pom. You should be using the spring parent, and define the latest version in the parent and then omit all version numbers, so that they get their version numbers from the parent instead.

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, thanks for the reply. So you mean I should define the version of spring-boot (which is the parent for all springboot projects) and not just spring-boot-starter-security starter package or spring-security-config version?

Comment: i would suggest you generate a project using the https://start.spring.io/ and see how they have defined their dependencies. The parent points out what general version you want of spring boot (for example 3.1.0) and omitt all versions from starters, and they will automatically pull in the best version that is defined in the parent for that version

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, thanks for the reply. But I am aware about code generation of start.spring.io. That's not what I mean to discuss on this thread. To give some context I am working on a project which involves upgrading the version of specific spring jars in a spring boot project. Since spring boot project manages the dependencies, I am looking for some feedback on the best practices followed industry wide.

Comment: Upgrading specific jars will give compabilloty problems as spring boot ships in versions that are managed by the parent. If you are upgrading individual jars you might get very difficult problems as jars are dependent on specific jar versions. Best practice is to upgrade the parent and never deal with invividual versions

Comment: Yes, I am aware about this hence raised a question on this thread. Any more suggestions on how do we upgrade spring jars specially incase when we get security vulnerabilities in the spring framework.

Comment: Moving from 5.6.3 to 6.1.2 is for a single is a major upgrade, if you insist on doing this i would suggest you start reading the change logs as there has been several updates between and it is basically impossible to say if anything is going to break. You are only making it tougher on yourself. Good luck